# Need to list SQL Windows auth users on each SQL server and rename the domain name

Tags: sql-server, logins

We are doing an AD Domain NetBIOS rename. We have about 20 SQL servers, and on each we have a series of logins like `OLD.DOM\sqluser1` etc. I want to do two things, and a third would be a bonus. I'm not sure how to put these together:

```
SELECT * FROM Sys.login_token
```

I think this will list the users I mentioned above? I'd like to put that into a variable and then run this I think:

```
ALTER LOGIN "OLD.DOM\variable_holding_username"
WITH NAME="NEWDOM\variable_holding_username"
```

So if I can go on a server, list out all of those `OLD.DOM\` logins and ALTER each of them, I'd be happy.

I'd be extra happy if I could hit each SQL server remotely and run through this, instead of doing each one separately.

Answer (score 3):

Unless you are actually deleting the user accounts in Active Directory and re-creating them, you don't actually need to do anything to the logins on SQL Server.

SQL Server references the accounts using the Active Directory SID, not the name.

You can test this by renaming an account in Active Directory and attempting to login to SQL Server with it.

Assuming you are using at least a semi-modern version<sup>1</sup> of SQL Server, you can use `ALTER LOGIN [DOMAIN\xyz] WITH NAME = [NEWDOMAIN\xyz];` syntax to modify the name of a Windows Active Directory login in SQL Server.  You can use the system DMV, `sys.server_principals` to determine which logins should be modified.  For example:

```
DECLARE @OldDomain SYSNAME;
DECLARE @NewDomain SYSNAME;
DECLARE @cmd NVARCHAR(MAX);

SET @OldDomain = 'MyOldDomain';
SET @NewDomain = 'NewDomainName';

DECLARE cur CURSOR LOCAL FORWARD_ONLY
FOR
SELECT 'ALTER LOGIN ' + QUOTENAME(sp.name) + 
    ' WITH NAME = ' + QUOTENAME(@NewDomain + 
    RIGHT(sp.name, CHARINDEX('\', REVERSE(sp.name)))) + ';'
FROM master.sys.server_principals sp
WHERE sp.type_desc LIKE 'WINDOWS_%'
    AND sp.name LIKE @OldDomain + '\%';

OPEN cur;

FETCH NEXT FROM cur 
INTO @cmd;

WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
BEGIN
    PRINT (@cmd);

    FETCH NEXT FROM cur 
    INTO @cmd;
END

CLOSE cur;
DEALLOCATE cur;
```

The above code will print a list of commands that could be executed to modify the logins for Windows User Accounts and Windows Groups.

You can run the above code against multiple servers by creating a group of servers in the Server Registration Window in SSMS, the right-clicking it and selecting "New Query", as shown here:

[image]

This allows you to run any query against multiple servers simultaneously, and see the results in one window.  The results have a "Server Name" column added automatically so you determine where each row came from.

---

<sup>1 - SQL Server 2008+</sup>

Comment: Yes, but we're not renaming accounts, we're renaming the domain name (NetBIOS only). Unfortunately the domain name does not use a SID in the same way accounts do. Well - of course there is a SID for the domain but the NetBIOS name doesn't resolve from the SID in the same way that accounts do. We have to change service account configuration, but for that, we can use company.com\username and that is staying the same. SQL unfortunately does not recognize the company.com\username format though.

Comment: I realize you're renaming the domain.  The "test" was only to show that SQL Server is "name independent", and only relies on the SID.  Surely when modifying the netbios name, Active Directory doesn't modify the domain SID?  If it did, that would mean you'd need to unjoin and rejoin all the domain servers, etc.  It would literally be a nightmare for what amounts to a metadata-only change.

Comment: Having said that, I'll add code to show how you can recreate the logins with a different domain name if you like.  What version(s) of SQL Server are you using?

Comment: We have a number of different versions, most of them are 2008 and newer I believe though.

Comment: Computers, however, pick up the new name on a reboot, or they will "release" and "register" the new domain name when they detect it, for example when a user first tries to log into their computer with the OLDNAME and then, after a Bad username or password message, NEWNAME will pop up. So we saw the list of logins with OLDNAME\account, and a domain rename and reboot of the SQL server host did not update these